# segmentation fault in lower/upper conversion

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

Here is my whole source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("usage: %s l(ower)/u(pper)", argv[0]);

    int (*convert)(int c) = NULL;
    int c;

    if (argc != 2)
      printf("usage: %s l(ower)/u(pper)", argv[0]);

    if (strcmp(argv[1], "l") == 0 || strcmp(argv[1], "lower") == 0)
      convert = tolower;
    else if(strcmp(argv[1], "u") == 0 || strcmp(argv[1], "upper") == 0)
      convert = toupper;
    else
      printf("usage: %s l(ower)/u(pper)", argv[0]);

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
      putchar((*convert)(c));

    return 0;
}
```

I compile this code with cc and run it on MacBook. 
A segmentation fault is received.

Comment: `and run it` - so you pass no parameters to the program? Well, `convert` is `NULL`, so what did you expect `(*convert)(c)` to do?

Comment: `(*convert)(c)` can be written as `convert(c)`

Comment: and `int (*convert) (int c)` can be written as `int (*convert)(int)`

Comment: A simplified version of your code runs well on https://ideone.com/jEKTfz

Comment: @pmg even the OP do not give details this is probably when the program is not called with l or lower or u or upper producing undefined behavior

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run the code with no arguments, or incorrect arguments, the printf statements tell you this, but then the program keeps on running, so you are probably calling the 'convert' function pointer while it is still set to NULL. This will crash before you see the messages telling you that you are not giving the program the correct args.
You probably want to put 'return 1' or something, after the print statements telling you the arguments are missing or incorrect. If you do, you'll need to put the whole 'if' or 'else' clause in brackets, or the return statements will be unconditionally exectuted.
Your indentation style is a bit non-standard. Perhaps this is why you overlooked the fact that there are no 'return' statements after the 'printf's telling you that the program is not being run correctly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("usage: %s l(ower)/u(pper)", argv[0]);

    int (*convert)(int c) = NULL;
    int c;

    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("uasge: %s l(ower)/u(pper)", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    if (strcmp(argv[1], "l") == 0 || strcmp(argv[1], "lower") == 0) {
        convert = tolower;
    } else if(strcmp(argv[1], "u") == 0 || strcmp(argv[1], "upper") == 0) {
        convert = toupper;
    } else {
        printf("uasge: %s l(ower)/u(pper)", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
        putchar((*convert)(c));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: if (argc != 2) {
 printf("uasge: %s l(ower)/u(pper)\n", argv[0]);
 return 1;
    }

Comment: It is my careless. Thank very much!

Comment: Your are brilliant

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems in your code, in order :

Why do you print the usage even the argument is valid ? the first `printf` must be removed

In

> ```
> if (argc != 2)
> printf("usage: %s l(ower)/u(pper)", argv[0]);
> ```

you detect if the number of argument is wrong, but in that case you print the usage and continue like if that number is correct, so if you call your program without argument you will call `strcmp` with NULL as first argument, with an undefined behavior

In

> ```
> else
> printf("usage: %s l(ower)/u(pper)", argv[0]);
> ```

if the argument is not l/lower/u or upper you enter in that *else* case, but in it you print the usage and again continue like there is no error, so in that case *convert* is not initialized, the behavior will be undefined when you will use it to call the conversion function.

---

One way to do is :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int (*convert)(int c) = NULL;

    if (argc == 2) {
      if (strcmp(argv[1], "l") == 0 || strcmp(argv[1], "lower") == 0)
        convert = tolower;
      else if(strcmp(argv[1], "u") == 0 || strcmp(argv[1], "upper") == 0)
        convert = toupper;
    }

    if (convert == NULL)
      printf("usage: %s l(ower)/u(pper)\n", argv[0]);
    else {
      int c;

      while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
        putchar(convert(c));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -g -Wall cv.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
uasge: ./a.out l(ower)/u(pper)
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out a z
uasge: ./a.out l(ower)/u(pper)
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out z
uasge: ./a.out l(ower)/u(pper)
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out u
a
A
P
P
(
(
```

Comment: Thank you very much. You give another way to solve the problem.

Comment: @MikeChyson you welcome, if you appreciate it you can up-vote and/or accept my answer as you want